# How to make Sphinx Autodoc show-inheritance option work with Intersphinx link to Django classes?

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I am using `show-inheritance` options of Sphinx Autodoc to list base classes of all my classes. Some of these classes link to Django classes, but unfortunately Intersphinx is unable to find them.

The reason for the problem is that Autodoc lists the base class as (say) `django.forms.widgets.Select`, but the objects.inv file Django provides lists only `django.forms.Select`. Although both these entries are the same classes and both are valid way to import them, but this throws off Intersphinx.

Is there a way to get around this problem? Is there any other source of Django objects.inv which has both the aliases listed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I have solved this myself. The most prudent approach seemed to me was to patch Django's `objects.inv` file with the missing references.

I have written a Java code to do this automatically. You can use it to create patched version yourself for any released versions of Django.

The code is at https://github.com/applegrew/sphinxutil.

Also, there I have made available the patched `objects.inv` file of Django version 1.4.1.